# update and watch jtables cells values while filling inside a loop

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, fill

in my java application I'm using some jtables and I fill each cell using jtable.setvalueat(i,j) inside a loop.

When jtable1 is filled, the loop for filling Jtable2 starts inmidiatelly and so on.

Everything works pretty good, but my application seems to be freezed with all cells in blank until all jtables and loops are finished and finally all jtables appear full filled at once.

If I use a JOptionPane to show some message after each loop ending I will see those cells have been filled up to that step.

My question:  Is there any way or trick to show cells values while are filled and not to wait until loop ends????

thanks a lot for your advises.

Comment: _Don't_ block the EDT; _do_ see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) re `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, but why you didn't write it as un answer??? you would have earned some points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loops that fill one `TableModel` after another block the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); the intervening `JOptionPane` allows the EDT to process the waiting updates. `SwingWorker` is a common way to `publish()` interim results; examples are seen in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish%28V...%29) and [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).